# Extending Django Admin templates

Tags: django

I try to modify django admin templates

I created custom template with the name corresponding to template, that I want to override.

I try the following

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
<h1>HELLO</h1>
```

If I reload the page I dont see h1 tag.

If I try

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}
<h1>HELLO</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I seen only h1 tag and dont see model's editing fields.

What have I do to see form and h1 tag in same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block field_sets %}

    {{ block.super }}
    <h1>HELLO</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

You must call the block from the source `change_form.html` template. Do that with `{{ block.super }}` as shown above. You can, of course, reverse the order between `super` and `h1` according to your needs.